# delete an element using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I wrote a script in order to add input clikking on a button and it works. I want to delete the last input created  using an other button, but my script delete all element.

### HTML

```
 <div id="dynamicInput">

      Title News 1*<br><input type="text" name="titolo[]" id="titolo_<?=$contatore?>"/><br>DescrIPTION 1* <br>
      <textarea class='textbox_studio' type='text' name='descrizione[]' value="" id="descrizione_<?=$contatore?>"></textarea><br>
      ImG News 1* <input name="logonews[]" id="logonews_<?=$contatore?>" class="textboxFile" type="file" style="margin-top:10px"/><br /> 
      <a>Attenzione: per una visualizzazione l'immagine deve avere dimensioni: larghezza:290px e una altezza154px.</a>
      <br>
      <p style="border-bottom:1px solid #78a300; width:520px;">&nbsp;</p><br>

 </div>


<input type="button" value="Add News" onClick="addInput('dynamicInput');" class="bottone" style="background-color:orange">
<input type="button" value="DELETE News" onClick="del_input('dynamicInput');" class="bottone" style="background-color:orange">
```

### JS

```
   var counter = 1;
   var limit = 4;

   function addInput(divName) {
       if (counter == limit) {
           alert("limit of  " + counter + " news");
       } else {
           counter++;
           var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
           newdiv.innerHTML = "Title News " + (counter) + "* <br><input type='text' name='titolo[]' id='titolo_" + counter + "'>" + "<br>Description News " + (counter) + "* <br><textarea class='textbox_studio' type='text' name='descrizione[]' id='descrizione_" + counter + "'></textarea>" + "<br>Img News " + (counter) + "* <input name='logonews[]' id='logonews_" + counter + "' class='textboxFile' type='file' style='margin-top:10px'/><br /> <a>Attenzione: per una visualizzazione l'immagine deve avere dimensioni: larghezza:290px e una altezza154px.</a>" + "<br><p style='border-bottom:1px solid #78a300; width:520px;''>&nbsp;</p><br>";
           document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newdiv);



       }
   }

   function del_input(divName) {

       var element = document.getElementById("divName");
       element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
       counter--;
   }
```

Comment: Your ID should be unique to the element in HTML. Then the getElementById function will only return 1.

Comment: You shouldn't use the quotes around `divName` in your `del_input` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You `dynamicInput` is the same in both buttons.  In the `add` function it ends up adding children to the `dynamicInput` and in the `del` function you end up deleting the entire `dynamicInput` div, hence all children are getting deleted.

To delete the `lastChild` you would do this

```
   function del_input(divName) {
       var element = document.getElementById(divName);
       element.removeChild(element.lastChild);
       counter--;
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can just remove the div using the id, which was created using counter value.

**HTML Code:**

```
       var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
       newdiv.id="div_"+counter;
```

**JS code:**

```
 function del_input() {
   var node="div_"+counter;
   var element = document.getElementById(node);
   element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
   counter--;
 }
```

**Live Demo:**

http://jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/kh09d5jf/1/

Happy Coding :)